# Improve AWK script - Compare and add fields

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I have a CSV file separated by semicolons, the file contains a sentiment analysis on customer reviews.

The views are grouped by field 1 and 6, what I have to do is add the last fields of each line of the group and then compare the sum with field 3. If they match, the comparison equals 1 if not 0.
At the same time, I have also compare fields 6 and 7 applying the same rule above.

Finally calculate the number of ones obtained for both comparisons separately.

I have a script made below, but I think it could be improved. Any suggestions? Also I am not sure that the script is fine..!

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=FS=";";
    flag="";
    counter1=0;
    counter2=0;
    counter3=0; 
}

{
    number=$1;
    topic=$6;
    id= number";"topic;

    if (id != flag)
    {
        for (i in topics)
        {
            if ((sum < 0) && (polarity[i] == "negative") || (sum > 0) && (polarity[i] == "positive"))
            {
                hit_2=1;
                counter2++;
            }
            else
            {
                hit_2=0;
            }

            s=split(topics[i],words,";")
            hit_1=0;
            for (k=1;k<=s;k++)
            {
                if ((words[k] == words[k+1]) && (words[k] != "") || (words[k] == "NULL") && (hit_2 == 1))
                {
                    hit_1=1;
                }

            }

            if (hit_1 == 1)
            {
                counter1++;
            }
            print to_print[i]";"hit_1";"hit_2;

        }

        delete topics;
        delete to_print;
        delete polarity;
        counter3++;
        sum="";
        flag=id;
    }
    sum += $(NF-1);
    topics[$1";"$6]=topics[$1";"$6] ";"$6";"$7;
    to_print[$1";"$6]=$1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6
    polarity[$1";"$6]=$3;

}
END {
print ""
print "#### - sentiments: "counter3" - topic: "counter1 " - polarity: "counter2;
}
```

A portion of the input data:

```
100429301;"RESTAURANT#GENERAL";negative;1004293;10042930;place;place;place;good;good;2.000000;
100429301;"RESTAURANT#GENERAL";negative;1004293;10042930;place;place;place;not longer;not longer;-3.000000;
100429331;"FOOD#QUALITY";negative;1004293;10042933;food;food;food;lousy;lousy;-3.000000;
100429331;"FOOD#QUALITY";negative;1004293;10042933;food;food;food;too   sweet;too sweet;3.600000;
100429331;"FOOD#QUALITY";negative;1004293;10042933;food;portions;portion;tiny;tiny;-1.000000;
103269521;"FOOD#QUALITY";positive;1032695;10326952;duck breast special;visit;visit;incredible;incredible;4.000000;
```

Output:

```
100429301;"RESTAURANT#GENERAL";negative;1004293;10042930;place;1;1
100429331;"FOOD#QUALITY";negative;1004293;10042933;food;1;1
103269521;"FOOD#QUALITY";positive;1032695;10326952;duck breast special;0;1

#### - sentiments: 57 - topic: 28 - polarity: 39
```

Comment: Sounds like you should request migration to [the Code Review SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Use meaningful variable names for scripts longer than a couple of lines. names like k1, k2, b1, x1, x2, xd, s, etc. are not useful.

Comment: So I have to do the same question in that section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote part of it, perhaps you can extend this further.

```
$ awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '
     {key=$1 FS $3 FS $6;
      sum[key]+=$(NF-1);
      line[key]=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6;
      sign[key]=($3=="negative"?-1:1)
     }
  END{for(k in sum)
         print line[k],(sum[k]*sign[k]<0?0:1),sum[k],sign[k]}' data

100429301;"RESTAURANT#GENERAL";negative;1004293;10042930;place;1;-1;-1
103269521;"FOOD#QUALITY";positive;1032695;10326952;duck breast special;1;4;1
100429331;"FOOD#QUALITY";negative;1004293;10042933;food;1;-0.4;-1
```

This only does your first check (I guess hit2), while also added sum and sign information (last two fields).